# how to use apply() in javascript

Tags: javascript

when read the heatmap code, I find a code like

```
this._store.addData.apply(this._store, arguments);
```

I am very confused about this usage of 'apply'.Is there any different in the code below

```
this._store.addData(arguments);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The point of using `.apply` here is that apparently the function arguments are in the array `arguments`. The equivalent code without `.apply` would be:

```
this._store.addData(arguments[0], arguments[1], ..)
```

Which is obviously troublesome if `arguments` is of unknown length.
Passing `this._store` again is only a necessity, it's not the point of this code.

Comment: No reason to have multiple identical answers, so dropping mine and +1 (even though I was first! ;-P )

Answer (score 0):

The two are not the same.

`.apply()` [as documented here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), sets the value of `this` when the function is executed and passes an array of arguments to that function which will be expanded into normal function arguments.

Your second code example passes an array-like object of arguments to the actual function rather than an expanded list of arguments so they are not the same.

As an example, if there are three items in the arguments pseudo-array, then the first option will call your function like this:

```
this._store.addData(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

And, your second code block will call it like this:

```
this._store.addData([arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

Though technically, it's not even passing an array, it's passing a pseudo-array that doesn't actually have the array methods.

---

The reason for using `.apply()` is when you have a list of arguments in an array or array-like structure and you want to call a function using that list of arguments as the arguments to the function (passed to the function as normal arguments).  It is very commonly used when you want to just forward the arguments from one function to the next or when you want to modify the arguments (e.g. remove one or change one) and then call another function with all the rest of the arguments.

Or sometimes `.apply()` is used only to control the `this` pointer and no arguments are passed (though `.call()` can also do that).

As a corollary, `.call()` is used when you know exactly how many arguments there are (e.g. you know there are two arguments AND you want to control the `this` pointer or `.call()` is often used when you just want to control the `this` pointer and don't have any arguments.  An advantage of `.apply()` is that you don't have to know how many arguments there are - you can just pass on whatever arguments there were (that's why it's particularly useful when forward the args from one function to the next) like when calling a base class constructor or when proxying for a function like what `.bind()` does.

---

This `this` pointer will be the same in the two methods because calling `obj.method()` will set the value of `this` to `obj` which in both of your cases is `this._store`.

Note, that these two would be the same:

```
this._store.addData(arguments);   
this._store.addData.call(this._store, arguments);
```